# jQuery - can't get dialog popups to pop up, they appear on the page instead

Tags: jquery

I have a couple small divs that I am trying to pop up when something happens, but they are not popping up, but instead appearing within the content of the page.

Would anyone know why that happens?  Also, the jQuery is supposed to show a spinner gif to indicate you should wait, but it doesn't render that either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is because you don't have the CSS file properly attached, and you haven't included the `/images` folder at a particular reference location to allow the images to be called. Check the console for errors regarding.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy interesting...which css file do I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though your intention is to use the jQuery UI Dialog, and the path to the google hosted CDN for the jQuery UI is wrong, it is not loading the jQuery UI library, getting a script failed to load on
https://ajax.googleapis.co/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

I do believe it is a typo, missing the 'm' off com, so should be
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

EDIT

if you want jQuery dialogs to initally be hidden, and then shown on a user action (like a button click) then initally construct the dialog with autoOpen set to false - as such

```
$("#loginpopup").dialog({ autoOpen: false} )
```

and then when required, they can be shown by

```
$("#loginpopup").dialog('open')
```

it appears that you are calling the standard jQuery .show method i.e.

```
$("#loginpopup").show()
```

and all this pretty much does is change the display: none to display: block, so if the element is not absolutely positioned (or somehow styled to display it where you want), then it will just appear where it normally would in the normal flow of the page

hope that helps?

Comment: yeah good catch on the typo! But I am still not getting the pop up to render like I wanted :(

Comment: something strange is happening in the code here, interestingly enough, I get a dialog popup correctly if I don't enter anything in the address and radius boxes and hit the 'Search for fans' button, still looking

Comment: OK, think I see what your doing here. If you have 'constructed' a UI dialog, and set the autoOpen to false, to show it again you, the code is $("#loginpopup").dialog('open') not $("#loginpopup").show( )

Answer (score 1):

Throwing up the HTML would help, but I suspect you need to set

```
position:absolute
```

on your div tags.

I'd need to see what you are doing with the spinner gif to be of help there.

Comment: all the code is on the home page of chernomorets.co - I just figured it would be easier to give a url than paste a bunch of code.